# How to write specific CSS for mozilla, chrome and IE

Tags: php, html, css, browser-detection

What would be the CSS conditional statement you can use to include specific CSS for IE, Mozilla, Chrome.

```
If IE  
#container { top: 5px; }  

If Mozilla 
#container { top: 7px; }    

If Chrome  
#container { top: 9px; }
```

What would be the respective 'If's' ?

Comment: What's with all the irrelevant tags? Most irrelevant one being [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bw51z5z.aspx)

Comment: Hey i never put that, though php is relevant!

Comment: I know, someone else did. Fair point on PHP though since you would use it for browser detection...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For that

- You can scan user Agent and find out which browser, its version. Including the OS for OS specific styles
- You can use various CSS Hacks for specific browser
- Or Scripts or Plugins to indentify the browser and apply various classes to the elements

### Using PHP

See

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php
- http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php-browser-detection-basic.php
- http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php_browser_detection.php (contains JS also)

Then then create the dynamic CSS file as per the detected browser

### Here is a CSS Hacks list

```
/***** Selector Hacks ******/

/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}


/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }



/***** Attribute Hacks ******/

/* IE6 */
#once { _color: blue }

/* IE6, IE7 */
#doce { *color: blue; /* or #color: blue */ }

/* Everything but IE6 */
#diecisiete { color/**/: blue }

/* IE6, IE7, IE8 */
#diecinueve { color: blue\9; }

/* IE7, IE8 */
#veinte { color/*\**/: blue\9; }

/* IE6, IE7 -- acts as an !important */
#veintesiete { color: blue !ie; } /* string after ! can be anything */
```

Source: http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

### If you want to use Plugin then here is one

http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: Paul also has a good approach for detecting IE without hacks or JS; see my answer below.

Comment: If IE detection is the only case, then using CSS conditional statements is the best option.

Comment: Even if you want to detect the non IE browsers, then you can use the hack free approach to handle IE and then browser specific hacks for the rest.

Answer (score 8):

You could use php to echo the browser name as a `body` class, e.g.

```
<body class="mozilla">
```

Then, your conditional CSS would look like

```
.ie #container { top: 5px;}
.mozilla #container { top: 5px;}
.chrome #container { top: 5px;}
```

Comment: How to echo the browser name?

Comment: @Starx `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: I know that, but how do you extract browser's name from it. I am saying this, so that you will make your answer complete.

Answer (score 3):

For clean code, you might make use of the javascript file here: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/
 By including the line:

```
<script src="css_browser_selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can write subsequent css with the following simple pattern:

```
.ie7 [thing] {
  background-color: orange
}
.chrome [thing] {
  background-color: gray
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you also have PHP in the tag, I'm going to suggest some server side options.

The easiest solution is the one most people suggest here.  The problem I generally have with this, is that it can causes your CSS files or <style> tags to be up to 20 times bigger than your html documents and can cause browser slowdowns for parsing and processing tags that it can't understand `-moz-border-radius` vs `-webkit-border-radius`

The second best solution(i've found) is to have php output your actual css file i.e.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.php">`

where

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css");
if( preg_match("/chrome/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
  // output chrome specific css style
} else {
  // output default css style
}
?>
```

This allows you to create smaller easier to process files for the browser.

The best method I've found, is specific to Apache though.  The method is to use mod_rewrite or mod_perl's PerlMapToStorageHandler to remap the URL to a file on the system based on the rendering engine.

say your website is `http://www.myexample.com/` and it points to `/srv/www/html`.  For chrome, if you ask for main.css, instead of loading `/srv/www/html/main.css` it checks to see if there is a `/srv/www/html/main.webkit.css` and if it exists, it dump that, else it'll output the main.css.  For IE, it tries `main.trident.css`, for firefox it tries `main.gecko.css`.  Like above, it allows me to create smaller, more targeted, css files, but it also allows me to use caching better, as the browser will attempt to redownload the file, and the web server will present the browser with proper 304's to tell it, you don't need to redownload it.  It also allows my web developers a bit more freedom without for them having to write backend code to target platforms.  I also have .js files being redirected to javascript engines as well,  for `main.js`, in chrome it tries `main.v8.js`, in safari, `main.nitro.js`, in firefox, `main.gecko.js`.  This allows for outputting of specific javascript that will be faster(less browser testing code/feature testing).  Granted the developers don't have to target specific and can write a `main.js` and not make `main.<js engine>.js` and it'll load that normally.  i.e. having a `main.js` and a `main.jscript.js` file means that IE gets the jscript one, and everyone else gets the default js, same with the css files.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Irish's approach to IE specific CSS is the most elegant I've seen.  It uses conditional statements to add classes to the HTML element, which can then be used to apply appropriate IE version specific CSS without resorting to hacks.  The CSS validates, and it will continue to work down the line for future browser versions.

The full details of the approach can be seen [on his site](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

This doesn't cover browser specific hacks for Mozilla and Chrome... but I don't really find I need those anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in your css file:

```
 -webkit-top:9px;  
-moz-top:7px; 
top:5px;
```

the code -webkit-top:9px; is for chrome, -moz-top:7px is for mozilla and the last one is for IE.
   Have Fun!!!

Comment: Readers beware, this is completely wrong, prefixed css properties are for non-standard implementations of experimental features, not every CSS property. The example will use 5px in EVERY browser (even if the prefixed version might be recognized the standard value would overwrite that) as `top` is implemented everywhere: http://jsfiddle.net/2bRGb/

Answer (score 0):

use agent detector and then with your web language create program to create css

for example in python

```
csscreator()
    useragent = detector()
    if useragent == "Firefox":
         css = "your css"
    ...
    return css
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link : http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

## 2 CSS Rules Specific to Explorer (IE CSS hacks)

Another option is to declare CSS rules that can only be read by Explorer. For example, add an asterisk (*) before the CSS property will target IE7 or add an underscore before the property will target IE6. However, this method is not recommended because they are not valid CSS syntax.

IE8 or below: to write CSS rules specificially to IE8 or below, add a backslash and 9 (\9) at the end before the semicolon.
IE7 or below: add an asterisk (*) before the CSS property.
IE6: add an underscore (_) before the property.
.box {

```
background: gray; /* standard */

background: pink\9; /* IE 8 and below */

*background: green; /* IE 7 and below */

_background: blue; /* IE 6 */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Place your css in the following script and paste it into your CSS file.

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { **your complete css style** }

For example:
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { container { margin-top: 120px;} }

Works like a charm.

Comment: It will work in IE? Or in Mozilla? Or in Chrome? This answer doesn't look like an answer to OP question.