# Text-security/List style type disc character

Tags: html, css, unicode

This applies to `<li>` with `list-style-type: disc`, but it also applies to `-webkit-text-security`.  I need the character used as this disc.  It does not seem to be `&bull;` (`\u2022`) since that is a different size.  You can see this easily with:

```
<ul><li>&bull;</li></ul>
```

Compare the two characters.

Is there an html special character for the list/text-security disc?

Comment: You can always change the `font-size` http://jsfiddle.net/2TAxz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i undestood it right you are looking for the "disc" mark symbol code?

What I found was: `&#9679;`

Source: http://brucejohnson.ca/SpecialCharacters.html

Comment: Looks like that's what I need.  Problem now is that Chrome uses a different character for `-webkit-text-security` (i.e. the bullet).  Is there any way to determine which character is used or otherwise change it?

Comment: What happends if you change the font on the form? To be more specific you need to change it only for chrome. Here is a great answer you can read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie I might have missunderstood what you are doing.

Comment: Changing the font could have other undesirable effects, but it may be the best option