# how to access the particular browser?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari

I want to access the browsers to apply the css. I know how to access Firefox and chrome using -moz- and -webkit-

How can I access safari and internet explorer browsers?

Comment: First of all, when a developer uses `-moz` and `-webkit`, he is not targeting those specific browsers, they are simply proprietary properties which are not yet accepted by w3c, as far as the answer goes you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie

Comment: They're called **vendor prefix** ("vendor" being the company that ships a particular browser, like Mozilla for Firefox or the rendering engine like WebKit for Safari and formerly Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

From [site point reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific)

- `-ms-`    Microsoft
- `mso-`    Microsoft Office
- `-moz-`   Mozilla Foundation (Gecko-based browsers)
- `-o-` Opera Software
- `-atsc-`  Advanced Television Standards Committee
- `-wap-`   The WAP Forum
- `-webkit-`    Safari (and other WebKit-based browsers)
- `-khtml-` Konqueror browser