# Different background position for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am using an image as background in a div,I want to use different postioning for  Firefox and Chrome.

**I want to use this one for Mozila:**

```
background-position: left -14px bottom -1px !important;
```

**I want to use this one for Chrome:**

```
background-position: left -14px bottom -2px !important;
```

Is it possible ? Please advice me..

Comment: hello again :p....please browse before you ask... => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie

Comment: @NoobEditor thanks again for your comment. 
I wanted -moz or -web-toolkit css attributes for this . i think its not there. thanks for the useful link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use specific selectors for FF and Chrome :

To target Chrome :

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   .yourElement {
     background-position: left -14px bottom -2px !important;
   }
}
```

To target FF :

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .yourElement {
    background-position: left -14px bottom -1px !important;
  }
}
```

That is way better than using User Agent.

Answer (score 1):

**First :** Try to reset your CSS before you code ?

I don't think they are different pixel things between Chrome and Firefox *(but not IEs)*

**Soloution :** Add a CSS reset stylesheet before your custom CSS

**Example :** http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

And re-check your positions agian

Good luck !

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it's not true that Firefox and Chrome use identical positioning systems.

Comment: @benny, im pretty sure about resetting CSS, will prevent pixel problems (at most) for modern standard browsers.

Comment: No, resetting CSS has nothing at all to do with the problem here. The question is "how do I target different browsers in CSS?" Resetting the CSS does not allow you to do that; it just makes it so it all looks similar in all browsers. @enguerranws' answer above is the best here.

Answer (score 0):

The code to check if browser is Chrome you can use:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

And firefox:

```
var FIREFOX = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```