# image background in div not the same in firefox

Tags: css

I have never had this happen before. I have an image in the background of this input field. I have it aligned using the X and Y positioning and I aligned it in Firefox. When I look at it in chrome, it is too close to the words "log in"  and is about 2 px too low.

I found this link on SO, but I guess I am not really following it. 
[How to write specific CSS for mozilla, chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie)

I was trying to use :before but could not get it to work. -webkit and -moz do not seem to be a good solution and I could not get thsi to work anyways.

the link is http://www.splitlightdesigns.com/oxbridge
UN - oxbridge PW oxy510

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: HTTP 404. You have a typo in the domain name, but once that is fixed the server returns a HTTP 404 for that page.

Answer (score 1):

every browser has its `user style sheet` that it applies on its own to some elements unless you override it with custom styling.

you should first of all, reset **all** of your styles using a 'reset' sheet, here is the first google result: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

just reset everythign and then start styling

Comment: Or, use [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) :) I typically prefer it over a hard reset.

Comment: @Terry well, yea it does look better xD but my point still stands :P need to override the browsers default styling

Comment: Normalize does override browsers default settings. Not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @Terry i didnt say that it doesnt. im just saying that as long as he overrides the default styling, it really doesnt matter which one he uses.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2px margin on submit input, but not in all browsers. It could be the problem, so set `margin: 0` to submit button (or set `margin: 2px` for all browsers).