# How to make SVGs responsive in WP 8.1?

Tags: svg, responsive-design, windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-10

I have problem with SVG images in full responsive website.
On Android and iOS devices everything works properly and images looks good, but problem occurs only on Windows Phone devices.

Is there any solution for this?

How to reproduce a problem:

Open [this webpage](http://www.popwebdesign.net/index_eng.html)  on Windows Phone 8.1 device in the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

firstly its not an issue related to Windows Phone. Secondly the IE on WP8.1 is version 11 and not 10.

Open your URL on IE 11 on any desktop you will see the image starting to break. Minimize the IE windows to match its width to Phone size you can completely reproduce this issue.

Next step? You might have to open dev tool to chk the actual CSS HTML causing this issue and fix it. Make sure to use *browser-specific css-rules* . chk [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie) SO link for more info.