# How to write css only mozilla and IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mozilla

How to write css only mozilla and IE? Targeting firefox and IE only with CSS. anyone help me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write specific CSS for mozilla, chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332117/how-to-write-specific-css-for-mozilla-chrome-and-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Use below i think will help you

```
/*IE*/
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

    }

     /*Mozilla*/
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {

    }
```